# Can Babel be used to transpile only JavaScript code in JSP files?

Tags: javascript, jsp, babeljs

I want to use Babel to transpile my .jsp files

What I am worried about is that in JSP file there are many languages not only JavaScript. For example: HTML, CSS, JavaScript code with EL Expression, as well as  scriptlet (Java Code).

Does Babel only change JavaScript code?

I'm considering standalone-babel but I'm not sure that does It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Babel is a JavaScript compiler."

From the homepage at https://babeljs.io/

You don't transpile JSP code. It is already read and compiled by your java build and/or server (tomcat, jetty, etc.)